# File modified after git clone

Tags: git, git-clone

After clone a github repository in my PC, a file is showing like a modified file. But the last modification in this file was done 8 months ago. How is possible? 
I tried execute "git checkout -- ." but the file continues like a modified file.

The .gitattribute file:
*.java text
*.scala text
*.xml text
*.properties text
*.properties.default text
*.sh text
*.pig text
*.py text
*.md text

The problematic file is a java source. And I'm using Ubuntu 12.10

Anybody have a tip/solution for the problem?

Comment: I've seen something similar and my best guess is there is some hook is modifying files on clone.

Comment: Can you do 'git diff' and see if there is anything meaningful that has been changed?

Comment: When I execute "git diff" is like all lines of file have been deleted and included again

Comment: Perhaps you are seeing an issue with the endlines.

Comment: What is `core.autocrlf` set to?  What kind of filesystem are you on?  NTFS?  FAT32?  SMB?

Comment: @EdwardThomson the core.autocrlf is set to input and the core.text is set to auto. My filesystem é ext4.

Comment: @vanz: Thanks, sorry, one more clarification.  When you say that it appears modified, you mean that `git status` shows it as such, correct?  If not, how are you determining that it appears modified?

Comment: @EdwardThomson Yes, exactly. When I execute a git status the file is shown like a file with modifications. The changes is not staged for commit.

Comment: Are there other files in the repository that don't behave like this?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345846/sometimes-git-tells-me-every-file-is-new-and-unstaged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just set a git core.filemode false will solve your problem.

Br,
Tim

Comment: Even after setting `core.filemode false` and  `core.autocrlf false` I still having this same problem. Any tips?

Answer (score -1):

Whenever `git` checks out some file (like after a `clone`) it sets the modified time to the current time.

Consider the following scenario: You have branches, creatively called One and Two. You check out One, and run `make`. Then you check out Two, and run `make` again. There is a certain file, called just that, that was last modified 1 and 2 months ago in the respective branch. If `git` checked out `file` with it's original modified time, each time you switch branches `file` will have been modified a *long* time ago as far as `make` sees. Not A Good Thing (TM).

Comment: That's only true if the file has changed.  If I am to switch branches and an item has the same contents in both branches (eg, if the destination tree item matches my current index item) then the `mtime` is not updated.  Otherwise, when I switch branches all my files would have their `mtime` updated and `make` would rebuild everything.  And that, too, would not be a "Good Thing".

Comment: Regardless, this doesn't answer why `git` would see the files as modified after it checked them out itself.

Comment: @EdwardThomson, I _explicitly_ gave the example with two different versions. After a `clone` the files _are_ checked out for the first time (there is no "unchanged version from the other branch"). `git` is smart, but it can't read minds to find out what the "correct" time would be, it just takes the safest option.

Comment: Your example includes this case, but your first paragraph talks about "whenever `git` checks out some file".  This presumably includes the `checkout` command, and it suggests that `mtime` is always set to current time.

Comment: And if the file hasn't changed, it isn't checked out ;-)

Comment: Yes, well, I'm not trying to be argumentative, I'm just trying to tell you that I found your answer unclear.

Comment: @EdwardThomson, if you think it can be said better, go ahead and edit my answer.