# Sometimes git tells me EVERY file is new and unstaged?

Tags: git, github-for-windows

I'll make a change to a file, go to the GitHub for windows UI. Commit my changes then hit the sync button. Then it says error, try using the shell instead. So I go to the shell and type `git status`. It tells me every file in the repo is new and unstaged. There's like 4,000 unstaged files.

This has happened to me 3 times now, on 2 different computers, on different repos, and even when working alone. Is this a common bug? Sometimes I get a detached head out of nowhere, or a .lock file is hanging around too long. What is happening. It takes me so long to recover from the mess each time.

Comment: Are you using remote mounts?  Do you have time sync?

Comment: I don't know what that is. I'm not doing anything weird so I don't think so.

Comment: If this isn't transitory, it suggests that something in the .git directory is becoming corrupted.

Comment: Or a bug in GitHub for Windows? Might be worth checking with the guys at GitHub support to see if this is an issue they're familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually a problem for Windows users who share repositories with Unix users and haven't set up their Git or editor end-of-line settings properly. See the man page for the following settings:

- core.autocrlf
- core.eol
- core.whitespace

See [Dealing with line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings#platform-windows) for more information.

Comment: Everyone on the repo is Windows. This even happens when I'm working alone. But maybe it's still worth looking into? I never set up any of this stuff.

Comment: @StephenSarcsamKamenar They still may have different EOL settings than you do, or something in your own tool-chain may be modifying line endings. The GitHub documentations says `[Y]ou may find that git wants to commit files that you've not modified. This is because git wants to normalize the line endings for you.`

Comment: Different line endings sounds like it would `modify` files, but not actually consider them `new` files added to the repo?