# Moved a git repo - now every file has an unstaged change.. (permissions?)

Tags: git, version-control, permissions

I've been working on a repo making commits - all went well. I decided to move the repo in to a directory which would allow me to use it on my local server. (I use virtual hosts but still prefer keeping virtual-hosts linked to specific sub directories)

After moving the files (plain `mv` on OS X) I had to change permissions for the app to work on my system, all good..

Then I went to commit my changes... **Every file has unstaged changes**. When I cloned the remote in to another directory to try and compare differences.. That repo also has unstaged changes on every file.

The repo was fine before I moved it, and I cloned a new one which was also displaying this peculiar behaviour; so the `.git` file can't be corrupt. The only thing I can think of is changing permissions, as I did it to the new repo too.

Could changing the permissions on this directory have caused this? I haven't had it happen before, but it's the only thing I can think of. If so, is there an easy way of resolving this? It's a bit of a nightmare right now.

I've seen one other similar question, but it doesn't appear to be the same: [Sometimes Git tells me every new file is new and unstaged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345846/sometimes-git-tells-me-every-file-is-new-and-unstaged). The answer to this question appeared to be users of different Operating Systems working on the same repo, and line endings causing issues. In this scenario, both developers are using OS X.

Comment: What does `git diff` show that the changes are?

Comment: @qqx - Wow, I think you're very very close there! ```old mode 100644
new mode 100755``` - Does indeed look like UNIX file permissions, but a quick google only returns issues on Windows systems.. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what changes were made to permissions that can indeed be the issue.  While git will ignore most permissions it **does** track whether or not a file should be executable.

Whatever differences exist should be shown by `git diff`.

Since you say in your answer that git diff shows:

```
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

that shows that the issue is indeed with permissions.  Git was originally told that the files should not be executable, but now the files in the working tree have the executable bit set.

You say that you've worked around the issue by setting `core.filemode` to false, but I wouldn't recommend that.  Instead I'd suggest either removing the execute permission from whatever files don't need it or commit the changes to the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

A massive thanks to @qqx who jumped on this in the comments section and asked what `git diff` shows. (Surprisingly, I had checked `git status` but `git diff` hadn't occured to me!

The output for every file was:

```
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

Meaning it **was indeed** file permissions. Something I did not think was possible with .git - doh!

If anyone is interested, the way I rectified this was:

```
git config core.filemode false
```

Comment: git doesn't track most permissions, but will record whether or not files have the executable bit set.  Git has recorded that the file shouldn't be executable, but the file on disk is executable.

Comment: @qqx- if you post that as answer I'll accept it; I'd rather accept yours than my own as you basically answered it for me - besides, you've also explained why this happened! :)